# None of the supported PHP extensions (PgSQL, PDO_PgSQL) are available

Tags: postgresql, pdo, ubuntu-16.04, adminer

i have enabled extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll and extension=php_pgsql.dll in my php.ini file but still unable to get adminer to work.

and also sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: sudo is in UNIX , whereas .dll is windows . Can you confirm which OS are you on

Comment: Yes am on ubuntu even am surprised how the .dll packages version got installed. how do i revert?

Comment: comment the line , look for php_pgsql.so and uncomment it

Comment: hi, satya i still dint find and .so files in my php.ini but i got it to work see answer below. can you tell me what i was missing? what should be my approach next time.

Comment: just make sure, you follow install instructions as per the OS you are on :)

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-pgsql

 cd /etc/postgresql/9.5/main 

 sudo nano pg_hba.conf 

local   all             postgres                                peer

should be 

local   all             postgres                                md5

sudo service postgresql restart
```

then you good to go :)

Comment: Why adminer cant connect to peer?

Comment: thanks, i have to run `sudo apt-get install php7.4-pgsql`

Comment: For php 7.3  sudo apt-get install php7.3-pgsql